# vba check if subform is on screen

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to call a function that updates the Content of a subform, only if the spefic subform is visible on screen. I tried it with *.IsLoaded* but this seems not to work. At least not like this:

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms(frm_BT_Halbzeug.Form.loadHalbzeug(Me.hidden_bauteil_id)).IsLoaded Then
        Call Me.frm_BT_Halbzeug.Form.loadHalbzeug(Me.hidden_bauteil_id)
End If
```

Unfortunately the subform is called everytime I update the mainform. How can I correct this? Help is appreciated.
Best regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim obj As AccessObject
Dim dbs As Object

Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject

' Search for open AccessObject objects in AllForms collection.
For Each obj In dbs.AllForms
    If obj.IsLoaded = True Then
        'Debug.Print obj.Name
        If obj.Name = "frmSubform" Then    'your main form
            If Forms!frmSubform!sfrmSubform.Form.Visible Then    'subform
                'Debug.Print "visible"
                 'do something.
            Else
                'Debug.Print "not visible"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next obj

Set dbs = Nothing
```

Comment: Great Work. Could get it running with only minor adaption to my program.